# How to include js to an php/html page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am kinda new to programming, I wanted to make this example run on my php page  http://jsfiddle.net/N78hs/2138/ but it just doesnot work for me

I've tried to create a .js file in (root/js) folder and call it on my php page but it didnot work for me.

here you can find head

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="/js/my.js"></script>
```

and here is the body

```
<body>
<div id="fullcalendar"></div>


</body>
```

thank you in advance

Comment: What doesn't work for you? Including the JS? The JS execution? Do you have any error messages in the browsers console? What does `my.js` contain?

Comment: FYI, nothing here is PHP

Comment: remove start slash from script, try 
<script src="js/my.js"></script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you did not connect all js and css libraries.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://qtip2.com/static/javascripts/libs/jquery.fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://qtip2.com/static/stylesheets/libs/jquery.fullcalendar.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://qtip2.com/v/stable/jquery.qtip.css">
<script src="http://qtip2.com/v/stable/jquery.qtip.js"></script>
```

Comment: Worked! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you have to include it in head part of your html. or on the bottom of the body tag.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to add you file in head section

```
 <html>
    <head><title></title>
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="~/js/my.js"></script>
      </head>

     <body>
    <div id="fullcalendar"></div>


    </body>
    </html>
```